# Import table from html into google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following table element from a website.

Using this formula it only extracts the 1st td ie class=`TTRow_left`
I want to extract both  class=`TTRow_left` and class=`TTRow_right` in a google sheet

Formula:
`IMPORTHTML("https://www.bsesme.com/","table",6)`

Html:

````
<table width="305" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   
<tbody><tr> 
              <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;" width="230px">No. of Companies Listed on SME till Date</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="AL">386</td>
          </tr>

              <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;" width="230px">Mkt Cap of Cos. Listed on SME till Date (Rs.Cr.)</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="MCL">58,225.56</td>
          </tr>
              <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;" width="230px">Total Amount of Money Raised till Date (Rs. Cr.)</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="Td13">4,132.16</td>
                
          </tr>


          <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;" width="230px">No. of Companies Migrated to Main Board</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="MB"><a href="markets/Migrated.aspx" target="_blank" class="tablebluelink">150</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;" width="230px">No. of Companies Listed as of Date </td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="CL"><a href="markets/SME_streamer.aspx" target="_blank" class="tablebluelink"> 236</a></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;">No. of Companies Suspended</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="CS">32</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;">No. of Companies Eligible for Trading</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="CET"><a href="markets/SME_streamer.aspx" target="_blank" class="tablebluelink">201</a></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;">No. of Companies Traded</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="CT"><a href="markets/MarketGnerLser.aspx?flag=T" target="_blank" class="tablebluelink">110</a></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;">Advances/ Declines/ Unchanged</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="Adv"><a href="markets/AdvDecCircutSumm.aspx?pgid=AD" target="_blank" class="tablebluelink">73</a>/&nbsp;<a href="markets/AdvDecCircutSumm.aspx?pgid=AD" target="_blank" class="tablebluelink">32</a>/&nbsp;<a href="markets/AdvDecCircutSumm.aspx?pgid=AD" target="_blank" class="tablebluelink">5</a></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;">Mkt Cap of BSE SME Listed Cos. (Rs.Cr.)</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" id="Dec">15,095.93</td>
          </tr>
         
                  <!--<tr>
          <td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;" width="230px">No. of SME companies migrated to main board</td>
          <td class="TTRow_right" style="height:22px;" >3</td>
          </tr>-->

          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way, You could extract that data with Google Apps Script - i.e. writing a function that reads the values (*those are returned by a separated request*).

You need to make a request to this url - which is the one that loads the data:

> https://www.bsesme.com/markets/MarketStat.aspx?&292022849

Values are:

```
bse$#$237|32|202|104|58|37|9|15,110.69|12|3,364.25|150|387|58,387.68|4,144.97
```

And then, extract the data.

I check the page's source code and that page is using javascript for read the data and rearrange it on the main page (i.e. `https://www.bsesme.com/`).

> Tip: Check the main page's source code and check a function called `function GetNotices(str)` - that function looks like has the logic for rearrange the data.

You will have to check deeper in order to figure out how you can extract this data on your spreadsheet.

Comment: This was useful. I used the data url you shared to pull in the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case `IMPORTHTML` would be able to return table data as long as it's not JavaScript generated, I tried checking the web page you are trying to scrap data from and it seems that the exact content that is missing is generated through JavaScript as it's not shown when disabled from the browser:

[image]

As you can see when JavaScript is disabled the content in the page is not displayed however the Table content `TTRow_left` is hard coded that's why the function is able to get this information from the web page:

> td class="TTRow_left" style="height:22px;" width="230px">No. of Companies Listed on SME till Date'

You will notice that `TTRow_right` is not displayed therefore the function won't be able to scrap data from it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It appears to be the case. Is there then a way to extract the data into google sheets or none at all?

Comment: Due to the way `IMPORTHMTL` works I'm afraid that it will not be possible as it's a JavaScript element and Google sheets doesn't support this type of content.

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)